# How to assert two list values with contains, but not a exact equal comparison in java

Tags: java, selenium

I am brand new to Java and i need some help. I have two lists.

```
List Expected = [Name , SSN, DOB];
List Actual = [Name , SSN];
```

I need to assert whether the List Actual values are available in List Expected, in other words, if both of the values in List Actual if it available in List Expected, my test should Pass. I googled and i tried to use this below assert statement. But my test is failing with the reason it is trying to validate the "DOB" from the List Expected.

```
Assert.assertThat("The Test Result Is.... : ", Expected, containsInAnyOrder(Actual.toArray()));
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
assertTrue(expected.containsAll(actual));
```

I strongly advise to stop using raw types (i.e. use `List<String>` and not `List`), and to respect the Java naming conventions (variables start with a lowercase letter).

Comment: Thank You. Its working. But if i have scenario with reverse case with the above given input, like if Expected having as [Name , SSN] and Actual having as [Name , SSN, DOB], then when i use this assertTrue, it just says "java.lang.AssertionError......" and not the exact error details like what is expected and what is missing compared to this kind of assertion -- "Assert.assertThat("The Test Result Is.... : ", Expected, containsInAnyOrder(Actual.toArray()));" Is there anyway i can use different contains assertion which also gives if any error then giving proper expected and missing details?

Comment: I would use assertJ (http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html): `assertThat(expected).containsAll(actual)`. Or, if you don't want to use the awesome assertJ library, use `assertTrue("expected should contain all elements of actual", expected.containsAll(actual));`

Comment: Yes. it was very useful. Thanks for assertj.